# How to set part of the x-axis in logscale on Gnuplot?

Tags: plot, gnuplot

I want to plot something that requires a logscale x-axis from [2-30] and a regular linear one from [30-2500].

This is the plot I want, the x-axis is partially logarithmic.

[image]

Can anyone help me? Thank you in advance.

Edit: Fixed range, added reference pic.

Comment: A range [0:30] in logscale will not work, do you mean e.g. [0.001:30]? What is the yrange? Should it be logarithmic or linear or also split? Please provide more details and ideally some code (people here expect some own effort) or graphs (hand-sketches would also be fine).

Comment: @theozh I added a reference pic, the post was pretty self-explanatory though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option besides "messing around" with `nonlinear` might be just to split your graph into a multiplot with 4 sub-plots.
Something like this for further tweaking...

**Script:**

```
### split log/lin plots
reset session

mySplitX = 0.33  # split point of log/lin in screen coordinates
mySplitY = 0.33  # split point of upper/lower plots in screen coordinates
myLeftMargin = 10
myRightMargin = 4

unset key
set samples 200
set multiplot
    set border 7
    set origin 0,mySplitY
    set size mySplitX,1-mySplitY
    set margins myLeftMargin, 0, 0, -1   # l,r,b,t
    unset xlabel
    set format x ""
    set mxtics 10
    set logscale x
    set xrange [1:30]
    set ylabel "my y-axis title"
    set ytics nomirror
    set mytics 5
    set yrange [0:6000]
    plot (2500*sin(x)+3000)
            
    set arrow 1 from screen mySplitX, graph 0 to screen mySplitX, graph 1 nohead dt 3
    set border 13
    set origin mySplitX,mySplitY
    set size 1-mySplitX,1-mySplitY
    set margins 0, myRightMargin, 0, -1   # l,r,b,t
    set xlabel " "
    set mxtics 5
    unset logscale x
    set xrange [30:2500]
    unset ylabel
    unset ytics
    set y2tics
    set my2tics 5
    set format y2 ""
    replot 
    
    set border 7
    set origin 0,0
    set size mySplitX,mySplitY
    set margins myLeftMargin, 0, -1, 0   # l,r,b,t
    set xlabel "my x-axis title"  center offset 28,0
    set logscale x
    set xrange [1:30]
    set format x "%g"
    set xtics
    set xtics add (30)
    set mxtics 10
    set ylabel "my Y-label"
    set yrange [-750:750]
    set ytics 300 nomirror
    unset y2tics
    plot (500*cos(x))
    
    set border 13
    set origin mySplitX,0
    set size 1-mySplitX,mySplitY
    set margins 0, myRightMargin, -1, 0   # l,r,b,t
    set xlabel " "
    unset logscale x
    set xrange [30:2500]
    set mxtics 5
    unset ylabel
    unset ytics
    set y2tics 30 nomirror
    set y2range[-75:75]
    set format y2 "%g"
    set my2tics 4 
    plot (50*cos(x)) axis x1y2
    
unset multiplot
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]

**Addition:**

The "secret" is just to set the margins and sizes of a the multiplot graphs such that it looks like one graph but with different scales.
In gnuplot check `help margins`, `help origin`, `help size`. You can basically check every keyword `help <keyword>` and get helpful information.

The x-label is set only in the first plot with an offset (`help offset`).

```
set xlabel "my x-axis title"  center offset 28,0
```

In the second plot it's just an empty space.

```
set xlabel " "
```

**Script:**

```
### split log/lin plots
reset session

mySplitX = 0.33  # split point of log/lin in screen coordinates
unset key
set samples 200

set multiplot
    set border 7        # show border at bottom,left,top
    set origin 0,0
    set size mySplitX,1
    set margins -1, 0, -1, -1   # left,right,bottom,top
    set xlabel "my x-axis title"  center offset 28,0
    set format x "%g"
    set mxtics 10
    set logscale x
    set xrange [1:30]
    set ylabel "my y-axis title"
    set ytics nomirror
    set mytics 5
    set yrange [0:6000]
    plot (2500*sin(x)+3000)
    
    set arrow 1 from screen mySplitX, graph 0 to screen mySplitX, graph 1 nohead dt 3
    set border 13           # show border at top,right,bottom
    set origin mySplitX,0
    set size 1-mySplitX,1
    set margins 0, -1, -1, -1   # l,r,b,t
    set xlabel " "
    set xtics add (30)
    set mxtics 5
    unset logscale x
    set xrange [30:2500]
    unset ylabel
    unset ytics
    set y2tics
    set my2tics 5
    set format y2 ""
    replot 
    
unset multiplot
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]

**Addition 2:** (alternative solution with `set nonlinear`)

Actually, if you go through the coordinate transformations you can do it simpler with `set nonlinear` (check `help nonlinear`). This has the advantage of avoiding `multiplot`, allowing to zoom-in in an interactive terminal.

**Script:**

```
### split graph in log/lin-parts via "set nonlinear"
reset session

### create some test data
set table $Data
    set samples 100
    plot '+' u (x0=10**(log10(30/0.1)/100*$0+log10(0.1))):(sin(0.01*x0)) w table, \
         '+' u (x0=$0*(2500-30)/100+30):(sin(0.01*x0)) w table
unset table

xmin   = 0.1       # "visible" x-minimum
xsplit = 30        # where to split the graph
xmax   = 2500
split  = 0.25      # graph ratio of lower log-part

xRangeH = (xmax-xsplit)*split/(1-split)   # "hidden" lower x-range
xminH   = xsplit - xRangeH                # "hidden" lower x-minimum
decades = log10(xsplit/xmin)

f(x) = x<xsplit ? xRangeH/decades*(log10(x/xmin)) + xminH : x
g(x) = x<xsplit ? 10**((x-xminH)/xRangeH*decades )*xmin   : x

set xrange[xminH:xmax]
set xtics 500
set mxtics 5
set xtics scale 1,1 add ("0.1" 0.1, "1" 1, "10" 10, "30" 30, "200" 200)
set nonlinear x via f(x) inverse g(x)
set grid x,y
set arrow 1 from xsplit, graph 0 to xsplit, graph 1 lc "blue" dt 2 lw 1.5 nohead

plot $Data u 1:2 w lp pt 7 lc "red" notitle
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: thank you very much, this is what I wanted, could you please help me by adding a few comments on how the code works? I actually want only the upper plot and by deleting the last two chunks of the code I can't seem to get the numbering of the x-axis and the x-title, sorry for being a noob

Comment: that's why it is important to ask precise questions about what exactly is desired ;-). I will add additional code.